# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ff_cog' referenced before assignment, unsolved

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement, rdkit

I have got this piece of code that does not really want to work.
I already tried to use Global, but it gave me a different mistake error (it tells me that ff_cog is not defined in that way), I tried to change the position of "numat", which was over  the if statement before, but nothing changed. Can someone Helps me, please?
I am 100% sure that there are valuee greater than dp. This if statement should be used to select the smallest distance among all the atoms whil they are calculated.
I cannot understand why it gives me this problem. I am using a similar for loop other two times in my program and it seems to work just fine. It`s the first time I come across with this error.
many thanks in advance

```
def ff(furthestcoord):
   #global ff_cog
   numat=0
   dp=np.zeros(0)
   for atom in mol.GetAtoms():
       atom_pos=np.array(mol.GetConformer().GetAtomPosition(numat))
       ffdist=np.array(np.linalg.norm(furthestcoord-atom_pos))
       print("this is ffdist",ffdist)
       if ffdist > dp:
            dp = atom_pos
            ff_cog = atom_pos
       else: pass
       numat+=1
   return ff_cog
``
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ffdist > dp:
   dp = atom_pos
   ff_cog = atom_pos
```

If the condition of this if statement is not satisfied, then `ff_cog` will never be initialized. That is why you are getting that error. You can try initializing `ff_cog` to an initial value to avoid the error.
You can do something like `ff_cog = 0` or `ff_cog = None` at the start of your function.

Comment: ok, I`ll Try asap, but the problem is that I` am returning ff_cog outside the for loop, so technically it should give me the last ff_cog that it has saved (which is the one I am interested in since it`s supposed to be the higher value). am I correct?

Comment: @DavideAnnese if this condition `ffdist > dp` is true at least once, then you are good. But, if that condition is never true, then there will be no "last ff_cog".

Comment: ok I managed to make it work, the problem was that after the if statement, in the first line, if the statement is satisfied,  iit was doing ```dp = atom_pos``` but the correct form is ```dp=ffdist``` because I want it to be saved and tehn be compared with the ffdist produced on the successive atom.